# Key in JSON not defined when passed to a CFC

Tags: json, coldfusion, cfc

I am passing a CFC a JSON, and there is a key that may or may not exist.  So, I am checking it with `isDefined`, but for whatever reason, coldfusion doesn't think it exists, when, from what I'm seeing it clearly does.  I have tried everything I can think of, but now I'm at a loss for what the problem is.

Here is the JSON pulled from Firebug:

```
[{"type":"USEQUIT","date":"01/01/2011"}] //the date, may or may not exist
```

Here is the only important part of the CFC function:

```
<cfargument name="attribs">
//debugging code
<cfif isDefined("attribs.date")>
    <cfdump var="date here">
<cfelse>
    <cfdump var="date not here">
</cfif>
```

I do this above in other function, and it works fine, but for whatever reason, I cannot get it to work here.  I'm assuming that I'm doing something wrong, but I cannot figure it out, so I'm asking the community.

Any thoughts?

Comment: What do you get if you dump attribs?

Comment: `[{"type":"USEQUIT","date":"01/01/2011"}] date isn't here`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CF sees the json you pass as plain text string until you call deselializeJSON() on it:

```
<cfargument name="attribs">
//debugging code
<cfset var ds_attribs = deserializeJSON(arguments.attribs)>
<cfif structKeyExists(ds_attribs[arrayLen(ds_attribs)], "date")>
    <cfdump var="date here">
<cfelse>
    <cfdump var="date not here">
</cfif>
```

Comment: I was pretty close to that prior to you answering it.  The problem with your code is that it throws an error as written.  `You have attempted to dereference a scalar variable of type class coldfusion.runtime.Array as a structure with members.`  I added this and it worked.  `<cfif structKeyExists(ds_attribs[arrayLen(ds_attribs)],"date")>` and it worked.